# Studying the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\frac1{n}\log\left(1+\sin\frac1{n}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Study the convergence of the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\frac1{n}\log\left(1+\sin\frac1{n}\right)$$

This is what I came up with

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sin\frac1{n}\log\left(1+\sin\frac1{n}\right)}
{\sin^2\frac1{n}}= 1 $$ 
This implies that

$$\sin\frac1{n}\log\left(1+\sin\frac1{n}\right) \sim {\sin^2\frac1{n}}$$

using the inequality $\sin{x}\lt x$   $\left(0\le x \lt \pi\right)$

$${\sin^2\frac1{n}} \lt \frac1{n^2}$$

Since  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$   converges so does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin^2\frac1{n}$ this implies the convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\frac1{n}\log\left(1+\sin\frac1{n}\right)$$

Is this right?

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: Thank you. I was not very sure.

Comment: Note that $\log(1+x)\le x$.  Hence, for $n\ge 1$$$0\le \sin\left(\frac1n\right)\log\left(1+\sin\left(\frac1n\right)\right)\le \frac1{n^2}$$

Comment: @J.Dane Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conclusion is right but we need to clarify some issue.

You have shown that

$$\sin\frac1{n}\log\left(1+\sin\frac1{n}\right) \sim {\sin^2\frac1{n}}$$

and then

$${\sin^2\frac1{n}} \lt \frac1{n^2}$$

thus by **comparison test** we have that since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$ also $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin^2\frac1{n}$ converges.

Now to conclude we have two choice:

1. Refer to **limit comparison test** to show the convergence of the given series given the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin^2\frac1{n}$
2. Refer again to the **comparison test** showing that (see the comment by Mark Viola)

$$\sin\frac1{n}\log\left(1+\sin\frac1{n}\right)\le \sin \frac1{n^2}\le \frac1{n^2}$$

As a simpler alternative, in my opinion, from here

$$\sin\frac1{n}\log\left(1+\sin\frac1{n}\right)\sim \frac1{n^2}$$

you can directly conclude by [**limit comparison test**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) with the convergent $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$.

Comment: How you can write $\sin\frac1{n}\log\left(1+\sin\frac1{n}\right)\le \sin \frac1{n^2}$ ?

Comment: Refer to the hint given here above from Mark Viola

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Mark Viola comment, we know $\dfrac{1}{n}<1$ is in first quadrant so $\sin\dfrac{1}{n}>0$, then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sin\frac{1}{n}\right)\ln\left(1+\sin\frac1{n}\right)<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sin\frac{1}{n}\right)^2<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\zeta(2)$$